# JAXB: Unmarshal xml to a final class

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal an xml to a final class (a library class that can't be modified to add jaxb annotation) using JAXB.

I tried recreating the class and adding the annotations, but I get null for elements.

[null result pojo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeMuN.png)

I tried using Document Builder Factory and I always get null for the root element too.

[null root node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrCE8.png)

Here is the xml that I want to unmarshal.

```
<AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
    <Audience>xxxx</Audience>
    <AssumedRoleUser>
      <AssumedRoleId>xxxxx</AssumedRoleId>
      <Arn>xxxx</Arn>
    </AssumedRoleUser>
    <Providerxxxx</Provider>
    <Credentials>
      <AccessKeyId>xxxxx</AccessKeyId>
      <SecretAccessKey>xxxxxx</SecretAccessKey>
      <SessionToken>xxxxxx</SessionToken>
      <Expiration>2022-08-29T09:26:47Z</Expiration>
    </Credentials>
    <SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>xxxx</SubjectFromWebIdentityToken>
  </AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>xxxxxx</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse>
```

I think that the problem is the namespace, I tried adding namespace to the XmlRootElement and nothing happened.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResponse",
    namespace = "https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/")
```

**UPDATE:** I tried deleting the namespace "xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/" manually from  from the xml input and the unmarshalling succeeded

How can I do that(ignore the xml namespace) when reading the xml in java ?